# How to create a federated table in MariaDB without specifying columns

Tags: mariadb, federated-table

I am trying to use the Federated engine of MariaDB 10.1.12 to create tables that are based on tables in a remote database. Following the [MariaDB instructions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-federatedx/#how-do-you-use-federatedx) about how to use the FederatedX implementation, in database `db1` I create a table as

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id     int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name   varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  other  int(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY name (name),
  KEY other_key (other))
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now when I want to see this table in a second database `db2` using the Federated engine, I can issue

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id     int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name   varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  other  int(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY name (name),
  KEY other_key (other)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://user_x:pass_y@localhost/db1/test_table';
```

All this is copied from the MariaDB documentation and works well. However, if I try to create the table without explicitly duplicating the definition of the table structure - an example given in the same documentation

```
CREATE TABLE test_table ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://user_x:pass_y@localhost/db1/test_table';
```

MariaDB responds with an error

```
ERROR 1113 (42000): A table must have at least 1 column
```

Am I missing something or is it not possible to use federated tables without specifying the individual columns?

Comment: I get this same behaviour with the CONNECT engine on mariadb 10.0.23. The docs indicate 10.0.2 is the release which introduced auto-discovery, so I don't get it either.

Comment: Just found [this](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-4555?focusedCommentId=36154&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-36154) indicating there was a bug with auto-discovery after the 10.0.3 release. This was written around 10.0.4.

Comment: Your comments encouraged me that this is a real bug; I have just opened a [new issue](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10069).

Comment: I got auto-discovery working with CONNECT engine by compiling ha_connect.so manually with default configure options for the same version of mariadb that my distro packages. My distro (fedora) strangely does not enable WITH_ODBC, and in solving that I somehow also fixed auto-discovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that with the standard installation of MariaDB on Ubuntu 14.04, the old Federated engine is active, not the new FederatedX variant. Only the latter supports auto-discovery of columns. In order to correct this, I took the following steps:

```
uninstall soname 'ha_federated';
```

to remove the federated plugin. After a server restart, the correct one is loaded with

```
install plugin federated soname 'ha_federatedx';
```

This loads the new FederatedX implementation supporting auto-discovery of columns. To view the installed engines, one can list them with

```
show engines;
```

If all is correct, there should be this line in the output:

```
| FEDERATED          | YES     | FederatedX pluggable storage engine |
```